# Folder Selection in MFC application as "BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS" undeclared identifier

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, mfc

I have made an application using MFC(Visual Studio 2010) and it has a folder selection button using MFC EditBrowse Control. It works in VS2010. But when I run that application at VS2012, I have the error of "BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS" undeclared identifier (error C2065). Why the error is there and I searched online but there is no proper answer for such problem.
Thanks

Comment: I have no problem using `CMFCEditBrowseCtrl` in VS2012, that identifier is unconditionally `#define`'ed so the problem must be in some code we can't see. Can you post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: There indeed is no proper answer for this question.  You can try adding the `#include <shlobj.h>` directive explicitly.  Doubtful it works, go take a look at that file to check it is in good shape.

Comment: @Roger Rowland and Hans Passant: My project is MFC 64 bit, it is the cause of the error?

Comment: @ Hans Passant: I put shlobj.h above afxeditbrowserctrl.h. Then it works.

Comment: @batuman; or add  "shlobj_core.h" before "afxeditbrowserctrl.h", both works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is that locate "shlobj.h" above "afxeditbrowserctrl.h". Then it works.
Thanks